# Difference between initialization:

Tags: c++

If there is a `struct` named `tree`. Then if I declare a pointer `ptr` in the following methods. Then what is the difference between these two statements:

```
struct tree* ptr;
```

and only

```
tree* ptr;
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote Java Script. I am studying Data Structure in C++. Tell me what is Difference. I am new to DS

Answer (score 1):

The first is an elaborated type specifier, and uses special name
lookup rules in C++, which ignores all non-type names.  The
second uses unqualified name lookup, and will find variables and
functions (which will result in a compiler error) if they are
present, e.g.:

```
struct Toto {};
void Toto();

struct Toto myVar;      //  Legal.
Toto myVar;             //  Illegal.
```

C++ allows such definitions for reasons of compatibility with C,
but you should avoid them; if you don't have both a non-type and
a type with the same name in the same scope, there's no reason
not to use

```
Toto myVar;
```

, and it's much more idiomatic.  Sometimes, however, you don't
have a choice: the Posix header `stat.h` defines both a `struct`
and a function named `stat`, and so you have to write:

```
struct stat fileInfo;
if ( stat( filename.c_str(), &fileInfo ) != 0 ) {
    //  error...
}
```

Such is the price of backwards compatibility.

Comment: "James Kanze" can u give me ur gmail id?? mine is 
bcs.12.22@gmail.com

Comment: i have pasted your above example it gives me error "toto does not name a type". what does it mean?

Comment: @UsmanRaza I presume that is the error message you got from the line I marked `//  Illegal`.  It means that unqualified name lookup found the function `Toto` (which effectively hides the `struct Toto`), so it's not a type, and the syntax where it is used requires a type.